# Minimal number of generators of subgroups of Noetherian groups

Tags: gr.group-theory

A group $G$ is *Noetherian* (or *slender*) if all its subgroups are finitely generated. Does this imply that the minimal number of generators of subgroups of $G$ is bounded above?

For example, if $G$ is a polycyclic group that admits a polycyclic series of length $n$ then every subgroup of $G$ can be generated by $n$ (or fewer) elements. This idea also applies for virtually-polycyclic groups.

It is unknown whether all finitely *presented* Noetherian groups are virtually-polycyclic. On the other hand, there are finitely *generated* Noetherian groups that are not virtually-polycyclic, for example the Tarski monster. However, all proper subgroups of the Tarski monster are cyclic and hence there is a bound on the minimal number of generators of its subgroups.

(See [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26059/example-of-noetherian-group-every-subgroup-is-finitely-generated-that-is-not-f) post for a related question.)

---

*Edit:* What if we restrict ourselves to finitely presented Noetherian groups?

Comment: A quasi-finite group is a group all of whose proper subgroups are finite. Deryabina-Olshanskii (Russian Math. Surveys 41 (1986), no. 6, 169–170) showed that a finite group is subgroup of a f.g. quasi-finite group iff it's the direct product of a group of odd order and an abelian 2-group. It's possible that the construction (or another one) provides a single quasi-finite group containing a copy of $C^n$ for every $n$, for $C$ a given cyclic group of prime order (this would answer your question negatively), but I don't have access to the paper (http://iopscience.iop.org/0036-0279/41/6/L10/)

Comment: Your question could possibly be true if restricted to finitely presented slender groups, since I think the only known examples are virtually polycyclic.

Comment: Yes, it is either true or open. I will add the question to the original post.

Comment: @Ian, indeed, *"Are all finitely presented Noetherian groups virtually polycyclic?* is (an open) Question 11.38 (due to S.V.Ivanov, 1990) from the *Kourovka Notebook*.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No.

> For any countable family of countable involution-free groups $G_1,G_2,\dots$, there is a 2-generated group $H$ containing all $G_i$ as proper subgroups such that each proper subgroup of $H$ is either cyclic or a conjugate of a subgroup of some $G_i$.

This is [Obraztsov's embedding theorem](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=sm&paperid=2990&option_lang=eng). Clearly, it gives a desired example if we put, e.g, 
$$
\{G_i\}=\{\hbox{all finite groups of odd orders}\}.
$$

Comment: This also gives an example of a Slender group that is neither perfect nor solvable!