# Example of a group satisfying Max which is not polycyclic by finite

Tags: gr.group-theory

Are there examples of a group satisfying max condition which is not polycyclic by finite. I was looking into Finiteness conditions-I by D J S Robinson, and it was posed as a question there, but the book was written around 1972, so i am sure there might be an example by now.

THanks

Comment: This is already answered in *[Example of Noetherian group (every subgroup is finitely generated) that is not finitely presented](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/26059/)*