# For a finite subgroup of an infinite group $G$, does its normal closure have infinite index in $G$?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

> For a finite subgroup of an infinite group $G$, does its normal closure have infinite index in $G$?

Or if not, is it true when we replace $G$ by some subgroup? That is:

> Let $H$ be a finite subgroup of an infinite group $G$. Is there always a subgroup $F \subseteq G$, such that the normal closure $\overline{H\cap F}^F$ of $H$ in $F$ has infinite index in $F$?

Edit:
As Derek points out, the Tarski monster is a counterexample. But the known Tarski monsters seem *not* to be *finitely presented*, see this answer: https://mathoverflow.net/a/26073/61732. So one could ask the above question for $G$ finitely presented. According to the last comment on the answer in the link, it is an open question if there are finitely presented Tarski monsters.

Comment: A Tarski Monster is a counterexample.

Comment: Ok, this is really good to know, thank you!  According to this answer: https://mathoverflow.net/a/26073/61732, the Tarski monster is finitely generated, but not finitely presented. So what if we assume $G$ to be finitely presented?

Comment: There are trivial examples without going into Tarski monsters. Check out infinite dihedral groups. This may better fit MathSE.

Comment: (My previous comment concerns the 1st question.) Derek solves both with Tarski monsters for finitely generated groups. But for the second question most groups yield a positive answer, for instance (a) residually finite groups (take $H$ of finite index with $H\cap F=1$), (b) non-torsion groups (take $H$ infinite cyclic). Since no infinite finitely presented torsion group is known, there is no counterexample known to the second question; also it is not known that there is no finitely presented quasi-finite group, and hence a positive answer to the second question is not known either.